# How can I store the resulting text on a website print into a text document?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ide

I have a site which is not yet public, so you won't be able to open the site, but a screenshot is enclosed below.

I open the site in Selenium IDE.
Then I click the button Skip To Summary in Selenium IDE.
This works fine.

My question is how (or If) I cat get the resulting text, shown in the right grey part of the screen into a textfile. Kind of screen scraping. If I could get to the html behind the screen it would also help me, but preferably the readable text as shown at the screen.

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Saskia Hermans

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer is not very helpful. and I hadn't expected such a reaction. 
I did try to find the answer my self of course. But I couldn't find it. so what research do you want me to share? I'm asking for a command, so what code do you want me to publish? All the ones that do not work? You can find the list here: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands
Probably what you find an obvious answer, is not so obvious to someone who is new to Selenium. I hope to get more helpful answers and this forum is also for people, new to a certain technique.

Comment: You need to better explain what you are attempting to do. With the current question, it's unclear. You need to provide the code/commands that you tried and why they didn't work... were there errors or they didn't provide the results you were looking for?

Comment: I'm sure your scenario makes sense to you but we can't read your mind. What information have you provided to us that would allow us to help you? We don't know the website, we don't know the relevant HTML, we don't know what buttons you pressed, we don't know what text appeared on the web page that you want to store, we don't know if you experienced errors, and you haven't told us what kind of document you want to store it in (MS Word, XML, JSON, CSV, plain text, etc.) I don't think you realize how little you've actually described in your scenario. Help us help you.

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear in first place. I have updated my question. Hope you now can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `store text` command. You would need to provide the locator for the element that you want to grab the text from.

See [`store text` in the docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands#store-text).

You could also just use `assert text` if you know what the expected text is supposed to be.

See [`assert text` in the docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/api/commands#assert-text).